# Locale from the parameter using @RequestParam not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using the below way to get the locale from the Spring `@RequestParam` provided parametres themselves. This works fine for any single request from the browser. But  if I change the locale on my web application screen and again hit the application, I am getting the value of the first locale itself from this `Locale` param.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register")
    public String register(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale)
```

Below is the localeResolver I am using:

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"
        autowire="default" autowire-candidate="default" lazy-init="default">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US"></property>
    </bean>
```

I have also searched the solution for this issue on Spring Forums but I believe the issue is not solved yet:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/109088-change-locale-not-working-please-help-me?view=stream

Ofcourse, I have a workaround to get he locale from request.getLocale() itself but just curious to know if anyone has any solution and root cause for this.

Comment: Please reword your question, I have no clue what your issue is. There is no request parameter for the locale so how on earth should that work. You haven't, apparently, configured anything for changing the locale (at least I don't see the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` anywhere.

Comment: I just want to delete this question now. Not sure how to do that! There is already discussion going on the Spring forum, the link for which I have provided above in my question.

Comment: The Spring Forum has been closed down for quite some years now and is only read only. As stated you don't have a change interceptor (at least not in your question) and you haven't shown the full configuration.